# kubernetes : Is is possible to install nginx ingress controller on V1.10 cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a v.1.10 kubernetes cluster.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:55:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0+coreos.0", GitCommit:"6bb2e725fc2876cd94b3900fc57a1c98ca87a08b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-02T16:49:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I would like to install an inginx ingress controller for this cluster.
I followed the instruction : [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/)

But, I keep having errors such as :

```
$ kubectl apply -f common/ingress-class.yaml
error: unable to recognize "common/ingress-class.yaml": no matches for kind "IngressClass" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

I checked, and there is indeed no IngressClass resource for my kubernetes version.
There are more errors as I continue the installation.

My question is :

Is there a document that describes the installation for old kubernetes versions?

NB. I installed my cluster manually (didnt use minikube, kubespary, ...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
error: unable to recognize "common/ingress-class.yaml": no matches for kind "IngressClass" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

kind `IngressClass` in version `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` was introduced much later then your version - in [v1.18](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#ingressclass-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io)

You can find appropriate nginx version like i described  below or, alternatively, you can upgrade you cluster to newer version and then use up to date  nginx ingress.

I think you can use old [Ingress Nginx versions](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases?after=nginx-0.26.2) or [old NGINX Ingress Controller versions](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/releases?after=v1.4.0).

For example [NGINX Ingress Controller 1.3.2](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/releases/tag/v1.3.2):

1. [Installing the Ingress Controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v1.3.2/docs/installation.md)
2. [examples](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.3.2/examples)
3. source code file on page available to download, that contains all necessary config files for deployment

btw, you can also check [NGINX Ingress Controller Helm Chart](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/release-1.3/helm-chart) and install nginx using helm. For that i think you ll also need upgrade your cluster.

Comment: Thx Vitalii. I will have a look